# How bad is to have 3 unique constraints in a table?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a table with articles. In this table I have `article_title` (varchar 500), `article_meta_description` (varchar 2000) and `article_content` (longtext). All of them are set to be unique (each of them, not together).

Why:

`article_title` because it's better for SEO

`article_meta_description` because it's better for SEO

`article_content` because I want to be sure there won't be unwanted duplicates made by a bad insert

I am aware that it may have an impact on insert performance, but I'm not sure about the size of impact. I also don't remember to have seen 3 unique columns in a single table somewhere.

So, how bad is what I'm doing ?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has a limit on index length.  It is 3072 bytes, I think.  That rules out having a `UNIQUE` on `article_content`.  Another column is (up to) 2000 characters; it is rarely realistic to have `UNIQUE` on such a wide column.

`UNIQUE`, in MySQL, does two things:

- Provide a uniqueness constraint, preventing duplicates from being inserted (unless `NULL`).
- Provide an `INDEX` for rapid lookup.

Assuming you need the constraint, not the index, here is a technique to clumsily handle such:

Add another column, say, `content_hash CHAR(32) CHARACTER SET ascii UNIQUE`.  Then stick `MD5(article_content)` in it.  (This can be done either in app code, by a trigger, or by a "generated column".)  And, because of the constraint, it will prevent insertion of identical 'content'.

Answer (score 0):

There’s absolutely nothing wrong with this at all.  Don’t try to optimize for insert performance unless you know you have a truly high throughput (think, thousands of individual inserts in a minute) use case.